# Setting a column header in a table model

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm not able to set the header of a new column created in a table view.

This is the code:

```
def addColumn(self):
    if self.tableView.selectionModel().hasSelection():
        indexes = self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedColumns()
        for index in sorted(indexes):
            print('Adding column %d...' % index.column())
            self.QSModel.insertColumn(index.column()+1)
            self.QSModel.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index.column()+1,'XXX')
    else:
        print('No col selected!')
```

The error I get is:

```
self.QSModel.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index.column()+1,'XXX')
TypeError: setHorizontalHeaderItem(self, int, QStandardItem): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error and [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setHorizontalHeaderItem) point out, the second parameter that is expected is a QStandardItem, not a string, in your case it should be:

```
self.QSModel.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index.column() + 1, QStandardItem('XXX'))
```

Comment: tks. Did you receive my email?